# Strange problem with Subversion - "File already exists" when trying to recreate a directory that USED to be in my repository

Tags: svn

So - I used to have a directory called mysql a few revisions ago.  I deleted it, and decided to start over - but when I try to create the new mysql directory - I keep running into the 'File Already Exists' error:

```
support:/etc/puppet/modules# mkdir mysql
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn add mysql/
A         mysql
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn commit -m " Test"
Adding         modules/mysql
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File already exists: filesystem '/var/lib/svn/puppet/db', transaction '11-r', path '/trunk/modules/mysql'
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn delete mysql
svn: Use --force to override this restriction
svn: 'mysql' has local modifications
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn --force delete mysql
D         mysql
```

I saw some other posts suggest forcing an update

```
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn status
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn update
At revision 11.
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn mkdir mysql
A         mysql
support:/etc/puppet/modules# svn commit -m "Test"
Adding         modules/mysql
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File already exists: filesystem '/var/lib/svn/puppet/db', transaction '11-s', path '/trunk/modules/mysql'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to work around it by reverting back to the last version that I had the mysql directory in, then deleting the contents of the directory, putting the new contents in it, and checking the new information back in.   Although I'm curious if anyone has a better explanation for what the heck was going on there.

Answer (score 62):

I had a problem like this when I **deleted a folder** (and sub-folders) and went to **recreate them from scratch**.  You get this error from manually deleting and re-adding *folders* (whereas *files* seem to cope OK with this).

After some frustrating messing around, found I had to:

(using TortoiseSVN on Windows)

1. Move conflicting folders out of working copy (so that I don't lose my work-in-progress)
2. Do an `svn update` which added old files/folders back into working copy
3. `svn delete` folder
4. `commit`
5. Copy new folder back into working copy (ensuring you delete all the .svn folders inside)
6. `commit`

Unfortunately it (A) requires two commits, and (B) loses file revision history as it only tracks back to the recent re-add (unless someone can explain how to fix this).  An alternative solution that works around these 2 issues is to **skip steps 3 and 4**, the only problem being that old/unnecessary files may still be present in your directory.  You could delete these manually.

Would love to hear any additional insights others might have on this.

**Simon.**

---

**[Update]**  OK, I had this same problem again just then, but the offending folder was NOT in the last commit, so an `update` didn't restore it.  Instead I had to **browse the repository and `delete` the offending folder**.  I could then `add` the folder back in and `commit` successfully.

Comment: +1 simillar issue - just directories, not files.  Reverted then svn delete, then svn add and it went away.  Odd.

Comment: +1 deleting the offending folder directly by browsing the repository fixed it for me.

Answer (score 17):

Had similar problem. To resolve it, updated from svn trunk with option of priority of local files.

```
svn update path/ --accept=mine-full
```

After You could commit as usual. Of course, be careful using it.

Comment: I only had one file stuck in an adding state. This svn update command resolved the conflict for me.

Comment: You'd have to run this command every time.  It doesn't make the original error go away.

Answer (score 12):

already had this type of problem.

my solution was:

delete the folder from svn but keep a copy of the folder somewhere, commit the changes.
in the backup-copy, delete recursively all the .svn-folders in it. for this you might run

```
#!/bin/bash

find -name '.svn' | while read directory;
do
    echo $directory;
    rm -rf "$directory";
done;
```

delete the local repository and re-check out entire project.
don't know whether partial deletion/checkout are sufficient.

regards

Comment: Thats where this whole thing started basically, I had deleted `mysql` a long time ago and I  - but thats when I got so fed up with "File already exists" that I just tried making an empty directory... It still wouldn't add it.  Also `find -name '.svn' -exec rm -rf {} \;`  much shorter way to do what your bash stuff does

Comment: Oh - Didn't notice the bit about deleting the entire repository and checking out again until a second read... If I ever run into that problem again, I'll be sure to try - Thanks!

Comment: good command, will replace mine with yours, thanks. i had that adding problem several times and checking out in a clean environment always helped me solving the problem. hope this works for you too if you run into it again. regards

Comment: I just had this problem while trying to add a new folder containing a file. To fix the problem, I simply reverted the add and then re-added it, all with TortoiseSVN. This is basically the same as your solution, except I didn't have to checkout anything again.

Comment: How about `find . -name '.svn' -delete`? It should be even faster than a `find` that spawns shells with `-exec`.

Answer (score 7):

This is a nasty one... mysterious error and no clear fix.

update/revert/commit did NOT work in my situation.  I hadn't done anything weird - just some svn moves.

What DID work for me was:

```
svn remove offender
svn commit
cd ..
rm -fR parent
svn up parent
cd parent
svn remove offender again
svn commit
copy offender back in (minus .svn dirs)
svn add
svn commit
```

Weird to say the least.  Basically, the `svn remove --force offender` wasn't doing completely removing for some reason.  Which is sort of what the error message was saying.  Only by removing the parent, then updating the parent, did this become obvious because then the offender reappeared!  svn removing offender again then properly removed it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem today when Xcode crashed during a branch merge. Somehow the file was uploaded to the svn repository but it wasn't recorded in the svn db properly. I ran the following commands in the directory where the file existed locally:

```
svn revert bad.file
svn del svn://my.svnserver.com/svnDB/path/to/the/offending/file/bad.file
```

Then I re-added the file from my local system:

```
svn add bad.file
svn commit -m "Re adding bad.file"
```

Success!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helping you, but I guess that when you do a `svn add mysql` after you've deleted it it will just reinstantiate the directory (so don't do a mkdir yourself). If you create a directory yourself svn expects a .svn directory inside it because it already 'knows' about it.

Comment: Sounds viable as well, although since I got it working by updating to an old revision and changing from there, I can't really test the theory.  Thanks for the hints though.

Answer (score 1):

1. rename the new path to temp
2. revert the new path (not temp!) so svn does not try to commit it
3. commit the rest of your changes
4. copy the path inside the repository: svn copy   -m "copied path" -r
5. update your working copy
6. mv all files from temp to the new path, which comes from the update
7. commit your local changes since revision
8. Have a nice Day including history ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on a project I run on Netbeans. 
I simply right clicked on the file and update to fix it (after SVN up).

Answer (score 1):

This solution merges smoothly and does not lose history:

1. Move /working-copy/offender to a temporary location.
2. Do an svn checkout of svn+ssh://svn.example.com/repo/offender to /working-copy/offender.
3. Manually move your files from the temporary location into the new checkout.
4. Delete the temporary location.

Answer (score 0):

This situation occured if there are object in repository, which creates by current transaction.

Simple scenario:

1. checkout some directory two times, as DIR1 and DIR2
2. make 'svn mkdir test' in both
3. make commit from DIR1
4. try to make commit DIR2 (without svn up), SVN shall return this error

Same thing when adding same files from two working copies.

Answer (score 0):

As per Atmocreation's solution, except you don't need to re-checkout the whole project, which is useful if you have existing work in progress.

Let's say you have a working copy:

```
/foo/
```

which contains directories:

```
/foo/bar/baz
```

and you're getting the error message on commit:

```
svn: File already exists: filesystem '/foo/bar'
```

Backup the contents of bar somewhere:

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp/code_backup
cp -r /foo/bar ~/tmp/code_backup
```

Delete the .svn control directories from the backup. Make sure you get this command right, or you can do pretty serious damage!! Delete them manually if you're unsure.

```
find ~/tmp/code_backup/bar -name .svn -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Double check that the copy is identical:

```
diff -r -x .svn dist ~/tmp/code_backup/dist
```

Remove the offending directory from the working copy:
    cd /foo
    rm -rf bar

And then restore it from the repository:

```
cd /foo
svn update bar
```

Copy back the modified files from backup:

```
cp -r ~/tmp/code_backup/bar /foo/
```

You should now be able to commit without the error.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the svn 'export' command. With this you can put a file or entire directory tree in the state of another revision in another branch.

So something like

```
rm file #without 'svn' in front!
svn export myrepo/path/to/file@<revision> .
svn commit
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the checkout takes place on a laptop and in this case subversion can not cope with the off-line synchronization. The problem is reproducable on an other laptop while on a desktop I have no problem checking out the same repository.

I hope this answer wil help you, it took me quite long to find out.