# Can I rollback a SVN commit that deleted then added files to a different path so that I can do a SVN move instead?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have lost the history on some of our files because we did a SVN delete, then a SVN add to a different folder. I know that SVN sometimes seems to have a bit of a problem when you add a file that previously existed. I am not sure if the same is true with the SVN move. Does anyone have any experience with this?

[This is the problem that I remembered.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407973/strange-problem-with-subversion-file-already-exists-when-trying-to-recreate) It seems that it is only a problem with folders. Not with files. But that might still present a problem for me seeing as the initial SVN DELETE -> SVN ADD created new folders.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
svn co -r <old_rev>
```

where `old_rev` is revision before your change

Then proceed with what you need to do and

```
svn ci
```

If merge is needed, then accept all the changes you performed.

Answer (score 0):

Its not the same `SVN move` is equivalent to `SVN copy` and `SVN delete`, in the `SVN move` case the files share their history with the original ones.

Comment: please read the question properly; that or you need to elaborate more. We already did Delete -> Add by mistake. I want to undo this and do an SVN Move isntead. I know SVN has problems with file names that previously existed.

Comment: Where is the Problem in that? you can revert to the revision before the files were deleted and from that point to do a move.

Comment: so is your answer yes, I can do a revert and the SVN move and SVN will NOT have a problem with the fact that the filename previously existed?

Comment: Im not sure now, googling the issue shows its not as stable as athe documentation states, the right way seems to be to copy the files from the old revision into the current revision. take a look at this instruction which handles exacly your case: http://www-old.canfield.com/content/svn-restore-deleted-file

Comment: @CouldyMarble I found the issue that I also had a while back. It relates to folder names, but I think I will also have this problem.